# How can i fill a class prperty form another class?

Tags: c#, linq

I have  class where i have the collection of FreeDressingItems, FreeToppingItems, FreeInstructionItems

that is like this each of which fill selectedCustomization i have another property in this class  `public string Items { get { return GetAllItems(); } }`

that i want to fill so that it keeps the all catetoryname for the same category type so that i can bind it to grid easily and display all its value in comma separated form.

i have following code could somebody help me how can i acineve this.

```
  public class selectedCustomization
    {
        public CategoryType TypeName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int SourceID { get; set; }
        public string Items { get { return GetAllItems(); } }
        private string GetAllItems()
        {
            switch (TypeName)
            {
                    case CategoryType.Dressing:
                    {
                        cFreeCustomization cfreeCust = new cFreeCustomization();
                        break;
                     }


                case CategoryType.Topping:

                    break;

                case CategoryType.SpecialInstruction:

                    break;


            }

        }

    }
```

this is another class cFreeCustomization

```
public List<selectedCustomization> SelectedItems
    {
        get
        {
            libDBDataContext cn = new libDBDataContext();
            List<selectedCustomization> lst = new List<selectedCustomization>();
            lst.AddRange(
                        (from xx in this.FreeDressingItems
                         select new selectedCustomization() { TypeName = CategoryType.Dressing, CategoryName = xx.DressingInfo.CatName, ItemName = xx.DressingInfo.Description }
                        ).ToList()
                        );
            lst.AddRange(
                        (from xx in this.FreeToppingItems
                         select new selectedCustomization() { TypeName = CategoryType.Topping, CategoryName = xx.ToppingInfo.CatName, ItemName = xx.ToppingInfo.Description }
                        ).ToList()
                        );
            lst.AddRange(
                        (from xx in this.FreeInstructionItems
                         select new selectedCustomization() { TypeName = CategoryType.SpecialInstruction, CategoryName = xx.InstructionInfo.CatName, ItemName = xx.InstructionInfo.Description }
                        ).ToList()
                        );
            return lst;
        }
    }
```

How can i make tiems of selectedCustomization in comma separated form?

Comment: If your property is calling a method behind the scenes, just remove the property and create a method for the same purpose instead.

Comment: so how can i access that collection here?

Comment: would you please gimme some idea i am toiling for long?

Comment: what is the use of "cFreeCustomization" class here?

Comment: cFreeCustomization is a separate class that holds SelectedItems.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet, than what is "class collections"?

Comment: no no that is cFreeCustomization  not class collections

Comment: lcarus..your suggestion of great avail..

Answer (score 1):

I believe the method **`GetAllItems`** should be like below:

```
private string GetAllItems()
{
    cFreeCustomization cfreeCust = new cFreeCustomization();
    var ls = cfreeCust.SelectedItems.FindAll(I => I.TypeName == this.TypeName);
    return string.Join(",", ls.Select(I => I.CategoryName).ToArray());  
}
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: but it re instansiate the whole object and collection is null always.

Comment: FreeDressingItems count 0

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet please post your cFreeCustomization class and how are you filling data into FreeDressingItems, FreeToppingItems etc.